# AngularJs two ng-app module webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am trying to figure a way to have my angular app use two modules. The main idea would be to separate login and the rest of the app. For that I need to override the module configuration. I simply don't want the user to be able to jump the login over to the normal app.

I am using angular.bootstrap following [Working with two modules in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522700/working-with-two-modules-in-angularjs)

```
 angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app']);
```

This is how far I have come so far with the two modules.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Euz6fK

Can someone help me?

Comment: skipping the login page should be controlled by the server backend, not by the front end. Also, you need to say what exactly you're having trouble with, you don't have a question with anything specific, just asking for general help and adding lots of code which no one will want to go through.

Comment: Well I thought the code would only be checked if you don't understand what I mean. I don't really know a better way to explain it. I would like to have a second app loaded after login with different routing properties. If there is such a nice app and routing behavior build on AngularJs I can't really believe I neeed to create two different websites and have one redirect to the other on login!

Comment: again, on login success, you can have the server on the back end send a redirect to the front end and you can use simple javascript to do window.location = "myNewURL"